# jQuery .on event handler and ES2015 arrow function

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm converting a project of mine to use ES2015, but I've run into a problem when it comes to jQuery's .on event handler, to do with the 'this' keyword naturally..

Here is my example code:

```js
$(".actionBtns").on('click', '.editButton', this.handlerEditBtnClick) //Would give 'this' the value of the button clicked
$(".actionBtns").on('click', '.editButton', () => {this.handlerEditBtnClick()}) //Would give 'this' the value of the class
```

I'm not sure the way I'm supposed to re-write the first line in the code above to use ES2015.

In the function handlerEditBtnClick, I need 'this' to be the class, but I also want access to the button that was clicked.

My attempt (the second line in the code above), doesn't give me access to the button DOM element that was clicked - at least in no way that I can think of accessing it.

Thanks,

Luke

**Edit**
This is the handlerEditBtnClick() function:

```js
handlerEditBtnClicked() {
  var $item = $(this); //This isn't re-written yet, so 'this' actually refers to the edit button that was clicked
  this.editItem($item); //This is where I need 'this' to be the class
}
```

You can see where I need 'this' to be two different things.. I'm not entirely sure how to call the editItem function from within handlerEditBtnClick other than this.editItem();

*Please note the names are just generic names, for ease of typing*

Comment: I guess the reason for wanting to re-write is because I want 'this' to be the class that the function is in.
I'm going to update my question with more code to show why I want to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `$(".actionBtns").on('click', '.editButton', () => {this.handlerEditBtnClick()})` 
`handlerEditBtnClick` function is called in diffarent context (`this` refers to class),
because `()=>{}` is equivalent to `function(){}.bind(this)` so you can do either

`$(".actionBtns").on('click', '.editButton', () => {this.handlerEditBtnClick()})`

or

`$(".actionBtns").on('click', '.editButton', this.handlerEditBtnClick.bind(this))`

then to access the button that was clicked you can always use `e.target`
(or `e.currentTarget` depending on your needs)

```
function handlerEditBtnClick(e) {
 console.log(e.target); // button that was clicked
}
```

Comment: @user1560593 yeah that is how your name appearing, you should be able to change in profile somewhere :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way (yes, in ES5 syntax):

```
$('.element').click(function (){
    $(this)===$('.element') //true
});
```

Propably it is because jQuery cannot bind selector to function when it is written "arrow way" (after translate to ES6).

Checked myself on few specific cases, or just use `event.target`.